# Is there any difference between \square and \Box?

Tags: box, amssymb

Here is my document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
  $ \square \Box $
\end{document}
```

Both produce boxes that look exactly similar to me. Is there any difference between the commands `\square` and `\Box`? If so what are the differences? If not why two commands for the same thing are present?

Comment: `amsfonts` has `\global\let\Box\square` unless `latexsym` is loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the doubt, you can clear it by asking TeX to tell you what the commands do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\meaning\square

\meaning\Box

\end{document}
```

You'll get

```
\mathchar"403
\mathchar"403
```

so the glyphs are exactly the same. At the end of `amsfonts.sty` (which is loaded by `amssymb`) you find

```
\begingroup \catcode`\"=12
\DeclareMathSymbol{\square}           {\mathord}{AMSa}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lozenge}          {\mathord}{AMSa}{"06}
\ams@DeclareMathSymbol{\vartriangleright} {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"42}
\ams@DeclareMathSymbol{\vartriangleleft}  {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"43}
\ams@DeclareMathSymbol{\trianglerighteq}  {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"44}
\ams@DeclareMathSymbol{\trianglelefteq}   {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"45}
\ams@DeclareMathSymbol{\rightsquigarrow}  {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"20}
\@ifpackageloaded{latexsym}{\@tempswafalse}{\@tempswatrue}
\if@tempswa
  \global\let\Box\square
  \global\let\Diamond\lozenge
  \global\let\leadsto\rightsquigarrow
  \global\let\lhd\@@undefined
  \global\let\unlhd\@@undefined
  \global\let\rhd\@@undefined
  \global\let\unrhd\@@undefined
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\lhd}     {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"43}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\unlhd}   {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"45}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\rhd}     {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"42}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\unrhd}   {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"44}
\xdef\Join{\mathrel{\mathchar"0\hexnumber@\symAMSb 6F\mkern-13.8mu%
  \mathchar"0\hexnumber@\symAMSb 6E}}
\fi
\endgroup
```

so as to provide the equivalents of the `latexsym` defined symbols.

Answer (score 14):

`\Box` is defined by LaTeX using the core latex fonts (`latexsym` package in the base distribution). `\square` is defined by `amssymb` using a character from AMS fonts, but by default it does

```
\global\let\Box\square
```

so they are the same

Comment: History: `amssymb` was created for use with AMS-TeX (the predecessor on which `amsmath` was based) before LaTeX was in use.